# Duplicate a column into a temporary table then convert data

Tags: sql, set, increment

Is there a way to duplicate a column from a current database table (copy all the column contents from table to a temporary table), Then
Convert the string value in the column and increment it by 1, then
Put all those values in a form of a string back into it's original table?

So pseudocode would look like:

```
 copy column1 from tblReal into tmpcolumn in tblTemp (set tmpcolumn1 as nvarchar(265))
 update tblTemp
 set tmpcolumn1 = 'TESTDATA' + 1
 copy tbmpcolumn1 from tblTemp into column1 in tblReal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually you want to change a string column, which holds actually a number, by incrementing its value by 1. Why would you need three steps for that? Just do an update statement on the column immediatly. I don't see why you need intermediate tables.

```
UPDATE tblReal SET column1 = column1 + 1
```

Piece of cake. You can use the cast function to transform the varchar to a number and back again in the update statement.

Comment: He may need some history table of his actions to see when and on which columns did he make the change, at least that's what I assumed.

Comment: True, lets wait for what he says :).

Comment: You can't increment a string value with a data type int I think.. Hence the whole export to a temp table, conversion then import to the original table with another conversion

Comment: Also I would prefer not to convert any fields or types of values in this table, rather do it outside, convert it again and export it back as a string

Comment: Also is there a way to make it versatile? (i.e choose a particular table or column or even multiple)

Comment: You don't need to export to another table to transform the data type. Use the CAST function as I prosposed in your query. Here is the api for micrsoft sql: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx maybe you use another db then go to that api.

Comment: You will not have to change the data type of the table. Just for the calculation in the update query you transform to number and after the calculation you transform back to varchar to store the result in the table.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Am I doing this wrong? 
`code`
select CAST(person_firstName as Varchar (50)) as person_firstName from newTable
update newTable set person_firstName = person_firstName + 1
`code`

Comment: It will be more something like this: UPDATE
  newTable
SET
  person_firstName = CAST((CAST(person_firstName as Number) + 1) as Varchar(50))

Comment: Why is a person_firstName a number anyway? Do you want to append the number 1 to a string or do you want to add 1 to a number? Those are two different things. In the first case you can forget about the casts and just do SET person_firstName = CONCAT(person_firstName, "1") instead

Comment: I want to add a number to the string and increment it. It shouldn't be a number. So end result under person_firstName should be:
TEST1, TEST2, TEST3.. and etc. 
Thanks ill give it a go now

Comment: So you want the first row to get from NAME to NAME1 and row 2 from SECONDNAME to SECONDNAME2? Or do you want a name NAME1 to go to NAME2? Both of them are still different from what we have now.